# how microservice communicate communicate in Kubernetes via envoy proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio, envoyproxy

how we can make possible the communication of services inside the Kubernetes via envoy proxy. I have two microservices designed in spring boot, one is called the `server` which has simple `GetResponse` by providing data to the `client` which is the second microservice. The `server` get response is;

```
@GetMapping("/server")
public String serverDemo(){
    return  "This message body sent from the server";
}
```

This request will be catch by the `client` microservice which simple return it. the `client` microservice is;

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Value("${URL}")
private String url;


@GetMapping("/client")
public String clientDemo() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside the client request");
        System.out.println("The url is: " + url);
        ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
        System.out.println("output is: " + forEntity);
        return forEntity.toString();
    }catch (Exception err){
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        return err.getMessage();
    }
}

@GetMapping("/clientgreet")
public String clientGreet() {
    System.out.println("Inside the client greet");
    return "Welcome to the greeting section...";
}
```

Here the `URL` is the environment variable which is provided in the kubernetes file by containing the `server` getresponse url. The `server-k8s.yml` Kubernetes file is;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
  labels:
    app: server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: 'feezankhattak2208/istioserver:istioserver'
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 128Mi
              cpu: 500m
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8001

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-svc
  labels:
    app: server
spec:
  selector:
    app: server
  ports:
    - port: 8001
      protocol: TCP
      name:  http
      targetPort: 8001
```

While the `client-k8s.yml` Kubernetes file is;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
  labels:
    app: client
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: 'feezankhattak2208/istioclient:istioclient'
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 128Mi
              cpu: 500m
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8002
          env:
            - name: URL
              value: 'http://server-svc:8001/server'

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-svc
  labels:
    app: client
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name:  http
      port: 8002
      targetPort: 8002
      nodePort: 30002
```

The `client` is accessible outside by hitting the following URL `http://localhost:8002/clientgreet` but when I hit its `/client` it says;

```
404 Not Found: "{"timestamp":"2022-02-09T13:29:53.109+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/server"}"
```

the url `http://localhost:8002/clientgreet` works right but the url `http://localhost:8002/client` fails.

I change the `env` values to `http://server-svc/server`, `http://localhost:8002/server` but it fails too.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: I'm assuming you are using istio, since the tags says so. Do you have any VirtualServices and DestinationRules deployed for this application?

Comment: No I am making the service as LoadBalancer so i access it from outside.